# snowflake 403 error while copy data in S3 "[Access Denied (Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied)]"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm getting the same error I followed the tutorials. Firstly, I created a data loader snowpipe that loads csv. That works. Then I wanted to load some tables in a bucket. Below is a summary of snowflake side:

(create a role and an access policy)

policy:

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::poc-qa-output/snowflake/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::poc-qa-output/",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "s3:prefix": [
            "snowflake/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

create a role then:

```
CREATE or replace STORAGE INTEGRATION test_it
 TYPE = EXTERNAL_STAGE
 STORAGE_PROVIDER = S3
 ENABLED = TRUE
 STORAGE_AWS_ROLE_ARN = 'arn:aws:iam::540705757804:role/snowflake-s3-role'
 STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS = ('s3://poc-qa-output/snowflake/', 's3://poc-qa-output/snowflake/csv-ingestion/', 's3://poc-qa-output/snowflake/metadata/')
```

retrieve the external id and snowflake user:

```
 DESC INTEGRATION test_it;
```

Creatre Trust policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::fake/fake"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "0000"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Create a pipe for loading the data into snowflake:
use schema snowpipe_db.public;

```
create or replace stage loading_stage  url = 's3://poc-qa-output/snowflake/csv-ingestion/'  storage_integration = test_it;

  

 create or replace pipe mycomp.public.medpipe auto_ingest=true as

 copy into mycomp.public.medaccount

 from @mycomp.public.loading_stage file_format = (type = 'CSV');

 show pipes;
```

The snowpipe works now bulking files into S3:

I add the bucket policy using the VPC id provided by:

```
select system$get_snowflake_platform_info();
```

I believe this is the problem but not sure:

```
{
      "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPC-only",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::poc-qa-output/snowflake/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-00000"
        }
      }
    }
```

Create a new stage:

```
use schema mycomp.public;

create or replace file format my_json_unload_format  type = 'CSV';

create or replace stage my_ext_unload_stage url='s3://poc-qa-output/snowflake/metadata/'

  storage_integration = test_it

  file_format = my_json_unload_format;
```

Create a view because I cannot use `where` in the copy:

```
create or replace view medview as select * from information_schema.columns where table_name ='MEDACCOUNT';
```

I get 403 here:

```
copy into @my_ext_unload_stage/metadata_MEDACCOUNT from medview;
```

I try and fail this too (403):

```
copy into 's3://poc-qa-output/snowflake/' from medview storage_integration = test_it;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the policy for VPC ID-based restriction and see if the issue is still reproduced? This is to narrow down if this is causing the issue. However, the policy looks good to me as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html?shortFooter=true#example-bucket-policies-restrict-access-vpc

Comment: I already did that. No change.